# Athens Museums & Monuments Combined Ticket Online Purchase

Tags: tickets, greece, pre-pay, athens

I am planning to buy the combined ticket from [this official Greek website](https://etickets.tap.gr/), but on the last screen I get the following text;

> **New: Skip the ticket office line!** If you accompany free admission
>   beneficiaries, buy your general admission and/or reduced-price tickets
>   online and gain direct access to one of the Acropolis fast-lane ticket
>   offices to obtain the free admission tickets quickly and easily, upon
>   proof of eligibility.

Does it mean that when I buy this online ticket, I again have to go and get a real ticket from this office, and only this process will be fast? I again have to queue with this physical combined ticket like anyone else?

Also, is there a way to get this *skip-the-line* power for real queues without registering with boring guide tours? Can I just pay and earn this right somehow?

Comment: I interpret that text to describe only the case of someone who is buying paid tickets to accompany people who are entitled to free admission (those people need to go to a "fast-lane ticket office" to have their eligibility checked). In other words, you buy online, and then go to the office for the people who need free tickets. I bought some Acropolis tickets online in March and was able to use them without visiting any kind of office, but there was no actual queue at the time, so I can't really answer as I'm not sure what the situation looks like with crowds.